# Peerjs video not rendering on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I have done a video call POC with peerjs. **It works perfectly with web to web (both video, audio & text)** but when I try to connect with mobile. It asks permission for audio and video. When I accepts ,I could see the mic icon and video icon on mobile which means audio and video is enabled in mobile. But I couldn't see the video on mobile and mobile's video on web. **NOTE:** Text chat between mobile to web is working fine only video not rendering.

**What I see on web**

[image: web]

**What I see on mobile**

[image]

**Code**

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});
// Peer
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require("peer");
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
  port: 443
});
const PORT = 3000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use("/peerjs", peerServer);

app.get("/", (req, rsp) => {
  rsp.redirect(`/${random}`);
});

app.get("/:room", (req, res) => {
  res.render("room", { roomId: req.params.room });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-connected", userId);

    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      io.to(roomId).emit("createMessage", message);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("Started")
});
```

**script.js**

```
const socket = io('/')
const chatInputBox = document.getElementById("chat_message");
const all_messages = document.getElementById("all_messages");
const main__chat__window = document.getElementById("main__chat__window");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;


let peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    path: "/peerjs",
    host: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXX",
    port: 443,
});
let myVideoStream;

var getUserMedia =
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    peer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");

      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
    });

socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      // user is joining`
    setTimeout(() => {
        // user joined
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
      }, 1000)
    })

    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.which === 13 && chatInputBox.value != "") {
        socket.emit("message", chatInputBox.value);
        chatInputBox.value = "";
      }
    });

    socket.on("createMessage", (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = msg;
      all_messages.append(li);
      main__chat__window.scrollTop = main__chat__window.scrollHeight;
    });
  });

peer.on("call", function (call) {
  getUserMedia(
    { video: true, audio: true },
    function (stream) {
      call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
        addVideoStream(video, remoteStream);
      });
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
    }
  );
});

peer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
});

// CHAT

const connectToNewUser = (userId, streams) => {
  var call = peer.call(userId, streams);
  console.log(call);
  var video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    console.log(userVideoStream);
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
};

const addVideoStream = (videoEl, stream) => {
  videoEl.srcObject = stream;
  videoEl.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    videoEl.play();
  });

  videoGrid.append(videoEl);
  let totalUsers = document.getElementsByTagName("video").length;
  if (totalUsers > 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < totalUsers; index++) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("video")[index].style.width =
        100 / totalUsers + "%";
    }
  }
};

const playStop = () => {
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setPlayVideo();
  } else {
    setStopVideo();
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const muteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    setMuteButton();
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const setPlayVideo = () => {
  const html = `<i class="unmute fa fa-pause-circle"></i>
  <span class="unmute">Resume Video</span>`;
  document.getElementById("playPauseVideo").innerHTML = html;
};

const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `<i class=" fa fa-video-camera"></i>
  <span class="">Pause Video</span>`;
  document.getElementById("playPauseVideo").innerHTML = html;
};

const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `<i class="unmute fa fa-microphone-slash"></i>
  <span class="unmute">Unmute</span>`;
  document.getElementById("muteButton").innerHTML = html;
};
const setMuteButton = () => {
  const html = `<i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
  <span>Mute</span>`;
  document.getElementById("muteButton").innerHTML = html;
};
```

**ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/1.3.1/peerjs.js.map"></script> -->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>";

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main__left">
        <div class="main__videos">
          <div id="video-grid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="main__controls">
          <div class="main__controls_block">
            <div
              class="main__controls_button"
              id="muteButton"
              onclick="muteUnmute()"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
              <span>Mute</span>
            </div>
            <div
              class="main__controls_button"
              id="playPauseVideo"
              onclick="playStop()"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
              <span>Pause Video</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <div class="main__controls_block">
            <div class="main__controls_button">
              <i class="fa fa-shield"></i>
              <span>Security</span>
            </div>
            <div class="main__controls_button">
              <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
              <span>Participants</span>
            </div>
            <div class="main__controls_button">
              <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
              <span>Chat</span>
            </div>
          </div> -->

          <div class="main__controls_block">
            <div class="main__controls_button leaveMeeting" id="leave-meeting">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              <span class="">Leave Meeting</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__right">
        <div class="main__header">
          <h6>Chat</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="main__chat__window" id="main__chat__window">
          <ul class="messages" id="all_messages"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main__message_container">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="chat_message"
            placeholder="Type message here.."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which phone are you running it on? And the browser you are using?

Comment: On iOS both Chrome & Safari and on Android in Chrome